# Footer view missing in android RelativeLayout

Tags: android

I am using header and footer and also use scroll view in within content part only.
if i run that application in emulator it display header and content part  only. Footer view is missing in my application.

Here my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>        
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

      <RelativeLayout      
          android:id="@+id/rl_header"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="40dp"
          android:background="@drawable/head" >

            <TextView android:id="@+id/txtTitle" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="@string/gebrauchte" 
            android:textColor="#fff" 
            android:textStyle="bold" 
            android:textSize="20dp"/>     </RelativeLayout>
            <ScrollView 
           android:id="@+id/scrollView" 
           android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_below="@+id/rl_header"

           > 

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_bikeDetail"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="#fff" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rl_bikeDetail"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
                    android:background="#fff" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtDetail"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:text="@string/detail"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtDetail1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
                        android:text="@string/pass"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="13dp" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtDynamic"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="267dp"
                        android:text="2175"
                        android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

                    <View
                                android:id="@+id/img_hrDetail"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="2dp"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/txtDetail"
                                android:background="#FF909090" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtBikeType"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/img_hrDetail"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:text="@string/biketype"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtBike"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="23dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/img_hrDetail"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
                        android:text="@string/belie"
                        android:textColor="#ff0000"
                        android:textSize="15dp" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_arwBikeType"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/img_hrDetail"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="280dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/arrow" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>



                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/img_hrBikeType"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"                 
                        android:layout_below="@+id/txtBikeType"
                        android:background="#FF909090" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtMarke"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/img_hrBikeType"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:text="@string/mark"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtMarkeBe"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/img_hrBikeType"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
                        android:text="@string/belie"
                        android:textColor="#ff0000"
                        android:textSize="15dp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_arwBrand"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/img_hrBikeType"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="280dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/arrow" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtModel"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/txtMarke"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:text="@string/model"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtModelBe"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/txtMarke"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
                        android:text="@string/belie"
                        android:textColor="#ff0000"
                        android:textSize="15dp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_arwModel"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/txtMarke"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="280dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/arrow" />


                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/img_hrModel"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"                
                        android:layout_below="@+id/txtModel"
                        android:background="#FF909090" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtErst"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/img_hrModel"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:text="@string/erst"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtErstBe"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/img_hrModel"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="115dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:text="@string/belie"
                        android:textColor="#ff0000"
                        android:textSize="13dp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_arwErstBe"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/img_hrModel"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="170dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/arrow"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtErstBis"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/img_hrModel"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:text="@string/bis"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="13dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtErstBel"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/img_hrModel"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:text="@string/belie"
                        android:textColor="#ff0000"
                        android:textSize="13dp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_arwErst"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/img_hrModel"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="280dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/arrow" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtLauf"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/txtErst"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:text="@string/lauf"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtLaufKm"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/txtErst"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="115dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:text="@string/km"
                        android:textColor="#ff0000"
                        android:textSize="13dp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_arwLaufBe"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/txtErst"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="170dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/arrow" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtLaufBis"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/txtErst"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:text="@string/bis"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="13dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtLaufBel"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/txtErst"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:text="@string/belie"
                        android:textColor="#ff0000"
                        android:textSize="13dp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_arwLauf"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/txtErst"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="280dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/arrow" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtHub"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/txtLauf"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:text="@string/hub"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtHubCcm"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/txtLauf"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="115dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:text="@string/ccm"
                        android:textColor="#ff0000"
                        android:textSize="13dp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_arwHubCcm"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/txtLauf"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="170dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/arrow" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtHubBis"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/txtLauf"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:text="@string/bis"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="13dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtHubBel"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/txtLauf"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:text="@string/belie"
                        android:textColor="#ff0000"
                        android:textSize="13dp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_arwHub"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/txtLauf"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="280dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/arrow" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtPre"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/txtHub"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:text="@string/pre"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtPreBe"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/txtHub"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="115dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:text="@string/sign"
                        android:textColor="#ff0000"
                        android:textSize="13dp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_arwPreBe"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/txtHub"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="170dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/arrow" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtPreBis"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/txtHub"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:text="@string/bis"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="13dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtPreBel"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/txtHub"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:text="@string/belie"
                        android:textColor="#ff0000"
                        android:textSize="13dp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_arwPre"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/txtHub"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="280dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/arrow" />



                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/img_hrPre"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"                
                        android:layout_below="@+id/txtPre"
                        android:background="#FF909090" />

                    <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
                        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtDynamic"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_arwBikeType"
                        android:background="#000" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
                </RelativeLayout>


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rl_Wo"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/rl_bikeDetail"
                    android:background="#fff" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtWo"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/imgHrule3"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:text="@string/wo"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" 
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

                            <com.InternetGMBH.ThousandPS.Utilities.SegmentedRadioGroup
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"        android:layout_below="@+id/img_hrPre"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"       android:id="@+id/segment_text"
            android:checkedButton="@+id/btn_egal">      <RadioButton
    android:id="@id/btn_egal"           android:minWidth="60dip"
                android:minHeight="33dip"           android:text="Egal"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:button="@null"          android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/radio_colors" />      <RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_gps"           android:minWidth="60dip"
                android:minHeight="33dip"           android:text="Gps"
                android:button="@null"          android:gravity="center"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="@color/radio_colors" />      <RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_eingabe"           android:minWidth="60dip"
                android:minHeight="33dip"           android:text="Eingabe"
                android:button="@null"          android:gravity="center"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="@color/radio_colors" />
        </com.InternetGMBH.ThousandPS.Utilities.SegmentedRadioGroup>
                    <!-- <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_egal"
                        android:layout_width="70dp"
                        android:layout_height="35dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/img_hrPre"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                        android:text="Egal" android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:background="@drawable/new_01" android:textColor="#fff"/> 
    -->
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtland"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/txtWo"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:text="@string/land"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtGpsStatus"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/txtWo"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="#000"
                            android:textSize="15dp" 
                             android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtlandBe"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/txtWo"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:text="@string/belie"
                        android:textColor="#ff0000"
                        android:textSize="13dp" />
                    <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtGpsValue"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_below="@id/txtWo"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textColor="#ff0000"
                            android:textSize="13dp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_arwLand"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/txtWo"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/arrow" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/txt_plz"
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/txtWo"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="230dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"

                        android:textSize="10dp" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/> 

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtmax"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/txtland"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:text="@string/max"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="10dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtmaxKm"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/txtland"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:text="200 km"
                        android:textColor="#ff0000"
                        android:textSize="13dp" />





                    <SeekBar
                        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_arwLand"
                        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txt_plz"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/txtlandBe"
                        android:max="490" />



                </RelativeLayout>       </RelativeLayout>
                </ScrollView>       





        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_footer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView"
            android:background="#fff" >

             <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_resetForm"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/rl_Wo"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/resetform" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_anze"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/rl_Wo"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="56dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_resetForm"
                    android:background="@drawable/redbutton"
                    android:text="Anzeigen"
                    android:textColor="#fff" />     </RelativeLayout>
             </RelativeLayout>



any one can help me what's the issue here?
```

Comment: hai,In footer relative layout just change android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView" to android:layout_alignParentBottom="true". now its working fine

Comment: You can put the solution as an answer as soon as the system allows you. In due time you can accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my answer,

in footer relative layout just add android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#fff" >
<Button....../>
<Button...../>
</RelativeLayout>
```